# how to access api with api_key Using Retrofit

Tags: android

I am new on android.Can any one tell me how to add the header for api_key using retrofit.I am not able to understand how i can do this.

I find this code from net.where i have to put this code in android folder structure.I am confused with this.where i have to add api_key.

```
// Define the interceptor, add authentication headers
Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
  @Override
  public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("User-Agent", "Retrofit-Sample-App").build();
    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
  }
};

// Add the interceptor to OkHttpClient
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.interceptors().add(interceptor);
OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

// Set the custom client when building adapter
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
  .client(client)
  .build();
```

Comment: The `addHeader` method looks like it would be able to "add the header for the api_key"

Comment: Where I have to write this code in android structure??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "structure"... anywhere in a Java file, really, would work

Comment: I mean in which file i have to write this code?I have to create new java file?and simply put this code in that java file?

Comment: Preferably in an Activity, but you are welcome to separate out your application into many file and packages... I assume you are following [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit). If so, maybe finding a complete code sample that uses Retrofit, would be better. Eventually, though, you need to call `retrofit.create` to make an API service

Comment: I simply create the java file??and give any name to that java file.

Comment: Yes? You must have at least one java file, say MainActivity,java to have any functional app. You also need to write some other code in there to get the app to run and display stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can store your api_key in your strings.xml file like this:

```
<string name="your_api_key_id" translatable="false">YOUR_API_KEY</string>
```

Then, in your OkHttpClient definition class, write a method to build your OkHttpClient like that:

```
private final static String API_KEY_IDENTIFIER = "key_identifier";

private OkHttpClient getHttpClient(){
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();
                HttpUrl originalUrl = original.url();
                HttpUrl url = originalUrl.newBuilder()
                        .addQueryParameter(API_KEY_IDENTIFIER, mContext.getString(R.string.your_api_key_id))
                        .build();
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder().url(url);
                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
        return httpClient.build();
    }
```

You should implement your client builder class with Singleton pattern, in order to have the client build centralized in one place inside your code